# What does this "R" mean in the Java debugger?

Tags: java

[I got this by debugging in Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzVTN.png).

It seems to be a java bytecode descriptor, but I've looked up the reference
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html and there is no field descriptor "R".

Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: ummm  **R**esources maybe

Comment: Or **R**equest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the output of the `toString` method of the `Request` class. It is not a Java thing, it is just something the developer put there. It might mean "request".

```
@Override 
public String toString() { 
    return "R( " + requestURI().toString() + ")"; 
}
```

Debuggers usually just output the result of the `toString` method when showing an object.